# Why does IFTTT dislike this RSS feed?

Tags: rss, if-this-then-that

I'm trying to get IFTTT to send me an email from this minimal test feed I created:

http://iftttrss.99b273199898d3dbd62e8db4ad65cf7f.madis.db.bcinfo3.barrycarter.info/

IFTTT accepts the feed when I add it, but the logs repeatedly say things like:

```
Feed Trigger Error about 6 hours ago
An error with Feed prevented your Recipe from working.
After five consecutive errors your Recipe will reset.
If errors persist, visit the Help page for support.
```

The Help page is, of course, unhelpful.

Here's what the feed looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?><rss version="2.0">
<channel><title>iftttrss.99b273199898d3dbd62e8db4ad65cf7f.madis.db.bcinfo3.barrycarter.info</title><description>DB_QUERY</description>

<item><title>Untitled</title><link>http://barrycarter.info</link>
<description>title: 2014-11-03 16:49:05, date: 2014-11-03, time: 16:49:05, </description>
<guid>9ff63fad584a8cfad58370f874c9a8d7d9642ead</guid>
</item>
</channel></rss>
```

Thoughts?

Note that simply editing the feed until it works isn't a great option, since IFTTT appears to check feeds only once every 3 hours(?).

Since the feed isn't rejected when I add it (like some of my older attempts were), I'd have to wait 3 hours between each test or something like that.

UPDATE: I deleted and readded the RSS action, and ifttt.com tells me this:

```
created 4 days ago
never triggered
```

My access logs, however show:

```
198.58.102.158 iftttrss.99b273199898d3dbd62e8db4ad65cf7f.madis.db.bcinfo3.barrycarter.info - [09/Nov/2014:18:50:04 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 696 "-" "Superfeedr bot/2.0 http://superfeedr.com - Make your feeds realtime: get in touch"
```

So I'm confused. This feed just prints the current time and date and is thus constantly changing.

Comment: Have you run it through an RSS validator?

Comment: @AlE. D'oh! Found several errors, working to fix them now, thanks! Was hoping IFTTT would've caught them at 'add' time, but apparently not.

Comment: @barrycarter Could you please add that as a self-answer then?  I'm not sure whether this particular solution would be applicable in any other situation, but if you can generalize what the issue was, that would be great.

Comment: @jonsca Waiting to see if IFTTT accepts the revised, validated feed. So far, the logs show it hasn't tried to access the feed since I fixed it.

Comment: @barrycarter has IFTTT accepted the feed? Might want to reactivate the feed and post an answer if it works

Comment: @Sathya Updated post

Comment: Have you contacted IFTTT support? I've found them to be very responsive.

Comment: That's so crazy, it might just work!

Comment: @barrycarter **1)** Your link is broken. **2)** if it worked - share your solution!

Comment: @arieljannai The question is ~3.5 years old. The answer directly from superfeedr is the correct one-- I think they've long since fixed the problem.

Comment: I know it's old, but it was unanswered :)

Comment: @arieljannai My fault. I've now accepted an answer. I hate it when I see unanswered questions that have really been answered, so I try not to be guilty of it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julien from [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com) here.
We are polling and parsing feeds on behalf of IFTTT. 
I just things on our end and, at this point, we are able to fetch and parse the feed... However, it's *ugly*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
<atom:link href="http://iftttrss.99b273199898d3dbd62e8db4ad65cf7f.madis.db.bcinfo3.barrycarter.info" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
<title>iftttrss.99b273199898d3dbd62e8db4ad65cf7f.madis.db.bcinfo3.barrycarter.info</title>
<link>https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-run-sqlite3-query2.pl</link>
<description>DB_QUERY</description>

<item>
<title>Untitled</title>
<link>http://barrycarter.info</link>
<description>title: 2014-11-10 09:34:26, date: 2014-11-10, time: 09:34:26, </description>
<guid>http://Untitled</guid>
</item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

Make sure you add *real content* in it and make sure it propagates (wait at least 15mins because you do not support PubSubHubbub apparently for now).

Add an entry like this

```
<item>
<title>My First entry</title>
<link>http://barrycarter.info/link-to-by-first-entry</link>
<description>The content of my first entry</description>
<pubDate>Sun, 09 Nov 2014 03:41:14 GMT</pubDate>
<guid>guid-for-my-first-en</guid>
</item>
```

Make sure you adda `pubDate` to your items too... this will only make things easier :)

Comment: Wow, an actual official answer-- this InterWebs thing is terrific ;) ... but seriously: this is just a test feed to make sure I can get things working: real data will come later. According to ifttt, "created 5 days ago never triggered". Is there a reason ifttt isn't seeing this feed as updated? What should I do to make this feed look like its continuously updated?

Comment: Please, check the addition above :)

Comment: Thanks, Julien! I added a pubDate and I just got a "Feed Trigger Error" in my logs. Time to contact support, methinks

Comment: Could you please provide a complete, minimal viable example?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I think I may have figured it out. Link should be in a different format:

```
http://www.domain.com/forum/rssfeed=1
```

And not

```
http://forum.domain.com/rssfeed=1
```

Also, validate it here: http://validator.w3.org/feed/

Comment: I should've updated this earlier, but it turns out ifttt/superfeedr dislike feeds with only one item.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issues and was able to correct by adding **https** to the feed instead of http.

For this particular example:

> http**s**://iftttrss.99b273199898d3dbd62e8db4ad65cf7f.madis.db.bcinfo3.barrycarter.info/